# Is there a way to deny jar startup but only allow a launcher(.exe) to start it?

Tags: java, jar, exe, wrapper, launcher

i have a small swing gui Java app and created a launcher (.exe) with launch4j.

As i dont want to have the jar included in the launcher i checked the option
**"Dont wrap the jar, launch only".**

Therefore the small exe will execute my jar.
But i **dont want the user to execute my jar** through the command prompt or anyway else.

is there a way to deny the startup of my jar?

regards
Nur1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Launch4j has `<cmdLine> Optional, constant command line arguments.` which enable you to pass some arguments to **`main`** method of application to run it. so you can pass some arguments through the `Launch4j` to `jar` file and check that parameter and prevent from running by command line.

Comment: I read both your and @DevilsHnd answer. This is actually a good idea to do this. Thanks. I think i will something like a hash generated from some files to protect the startup.

Answer (score 2):

Have the launcher send a special command line argument that will be read by the **main()** method of your Startup JAR file. Check for this startup argument from within your startup JAR file **main()** method and if this argument isn't valid or simply isn't there....issue a: `System.exit(0);` or whatever.